Immediately interrupting Bokeh processes using a button click
I'm working on a Bokeh application where I have a function update_data() that performs some time-consuming tasks. I want to add a way to immediately interrupt all ongoing processes when a button is clicked. The problem is that when I click the "Interrupt" button, the command to interrupt the process gets queued and only executes after the current process (e.g., update_data()) finishes, which can take up to 20 seconds. This is not desirable.
I've tried using a separate thread to handle the button click event and set a global variable to indicate the interruption, but it doesn't work as expected. The interruption still gets queued and doesn't immediately stop the ongoing process.
Here's a simplified version of my update_data() function and initialize_document() function in the main.py file:
def update_data():
    # ... code for updating data ...
def initialize_document():
    global layout
    layout = create_layout()
    try:
        curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update_data, 31683)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in update_data: {str(e)}")
    # ... more periodic callbacks ...
    curdoc().add_root(layout)

I've tried using a separate thread to listen for button click events and raise an exception to interrupt the process, but it doesn't seem to work effectively.
Can anyone suggest an effective solution to immediately interrupt Bokeh processes using a button click, without waiting for the current process to finish? I'm open to any ideas or alternative approaches.
Thank you in advance for your help!
